# Mongodb in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get my app to return something from the mongodb server its connected to but every time it returns :

```
{col : 
    {manager:
         {driver:[object],
          helper:[object],
    .
    .
    .
    query{}}
```

in my app.js i wrote :

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/Messages');

var collection = db.get('msgCollection');
var a= collection.find({});
console.log(a);
```

I checked and the database and collection exist. If i write in the mongo console db.msgCollection.find() it works

Any one knows what the problem ?
Thank you!

Comment: You have to use or callback, or resolve promise for finding elements. It's asynchronous code.

Comment: What do you mean? the second 3 lines are inside app.get('/', function (req, res) {...});

Comment: I suggest learning about node.js and its asyncrhonous nature more. You will have to deal with it all the time if You want to create apps in node.

Answer (score 0):

Monk's API is asynchronous (as is most of nodejs api).
To get results from query, You have to:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/Messages');

var collection = db.get('msgCollection');
collection.find({}, function(err, data) {
  //handle error
  console.log(data);
});
```

Or use promises.

Comment: You can find examples of monk promises at https://github.com/Automattic/monk. keep in mind that its not typical promise implementantion, but event listener variation of it.